# ParameterizedCron triggers multiple jobs in a declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, parameterized, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to run multiple test lists using the [Parameterized Scheduler](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/#plugin-content-scripted-pipeline-example) inside a scripted pipeline.

The cron works fine for the **2.30pm** and triggers *list_id=163*, but at **3pm** it triggers both *list_id=119* and *list_id=163* . Any suggestions on how to tackle this, or am I missing a parameter ?

Thank you

```
properties([parameters([
         string(name: 'TEST_LIST_ID', defaultValue: '163', description: 'Feature test 1'),
         string(name: 'TEST_LIST_ID', defaultValue: '119', description: 'Feature test 2')
]),
pipelineTriggers([parameterizedCron('''
                   H/30 14 * * 1-5 %TEST_LIST_ID=163
                   H 15 * * 1-5 %TEST_LIST_ID=119
                   ''')])
```

Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
I was able to solve the issue of multiple triggers by spacing out the cron time and also by using changing the order of the crons
For eg: My `jenkinsfile` has 12 crons, so I ordered the crons in decreasing order of time while also making sure there is enough time between subsequent jobs.